# AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect' error when doing collision

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to make collision detection for my game using instances. Here's the code:

```
class Paddle:
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, rect):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, width, height)
class Ball:
    coordinateX = 600
    coordinateY = 300
    velocity = [random.randint(0,1),random.randint(-1,1)]

player = (Paddle(1100, 300, 10, 30, (1100, 300, 10, 30)))
enemy = Paddle(100, 300, 10, 30, (100, 30, 10, 30))
ball = (Ball.coordinateX, Ball.coordinateY, 15)
```

And later on:

```
ballRect = pygame.rect.Rect(Ball.coordinateX, Ball.coordinateY, 10, 10)
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, ballRect):
    bounce()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when creating the `rect` attribute for your ball, it should be `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)` (assuming you import Pygame with `import pygame`). That should handle your `AttributeError`. Same goes for your `ballRect`, `ballRect = pygame.Rect(Ball.coordinateX, Ball.coordinateY, 10, 10)`.

Next, you're using the wrong rect collision detection function. `pygame.sprite` refers to something completely different in Pygame (its `Sprite` objects), and neither your `Ball` nor `Paddle` class are Pygame Sprites, from the code you wrote. Thus, calling `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` makes no sense here.

Instead, you should simply use `rect.colliderect`, like so:

```
if rect.colliderect(other_rect):
    # Colliding!
    print("Stop touching me!")
```

or in your case:

```
if player.rect.colliderect(ballRect):
    bounce()
```

Furthermore, you don't need to pass a `rect` as an argument to your `Paddle` initialization, because it's never used. The object's `rect` in completely generated from your other arguments.

Finally, your `Ball` class and instantiation code seems a little bit off. You should generate and initialize it like you do for `Paddle`.

**EDIT** One last thing. In pygame, when you create an object with a `rect` attribute, you no longer need to assign `x` and `y` values to the object, because whenever you'll need them, say, in a `blit`, you can just pass the `rect` directly (or `rect.x` and `rect.y` in some edge cases) as the position argument, and pygame will nicely handle the rest.

Here's what your code should look like (with a few other things fixed):

```
class Paddle():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

class Ball():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.velocity = [random.randint(0,1),random.randint(-1,1)]

player = Paddle(1100, 300, 10, 30)
enemy = Paddle(100, 300, 10, 30)
ball = Ball(600, 300, 10, 10)

# Other stuff

# Collision checking
if player.rect.colliderect(ball.rect):
    bounce()
```

Comment: Good answer, but some more things while your at it: in the `Paddle` class, all attributes except `rect` can be removed, since the position and size is already stored in `rect`. In the `Ball` class, `coordinateX` and `coordinateY` can also be removed for the same reason.

Comment: @sloth I totally agree with you, but I was afraid that OP might be using it specifically for some other reason. I'll update the answer to include this.

Answer (score 2):

As the module name 'sprite' hints, the function `pygame.sprite.collide_rect` and all other collision detection functions expect `Sprite` instances as arguments.

Look at the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html?highlight=group#pygame.sprite.collide_rect):

> `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`
> *Collision detection between two sprites, using rects.*
> `collide_rect(left, right) -> bool`
>
> Tests for collision between two sprites. Uses the pygame rect colliderect function to calculate the collision. Intended to be passed as a collided callback function to the *collide functions. Sprites must have a "rect" attributes.

(Also, usually you don't use this function directly, but together with a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)).

So either start using the `Sprite` class (which is what you should do) or use the functions that the `Rect` class provides, like [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html?highlight=rect#pygame.Rect.colliderect):

> `colliderect()`
> *test if two rectangles overlap*
> `colliderect(Rect) -> bool`
>
> Returns true if any portion of either rectangle overlap (except the top+bottom or left+right edges).

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://kite.com/python/docs/pygame.sprite.collide_rect), the `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` is used to detect collision between two **sprites**, however you are passing a `pygame.rect.Rect()` object, and a **Paddle** object.

So, what you need to do is have two objects created using `pygame.sprite.Sprite` and then detect collision between them, if you want to use `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`